# Expose an unsecure Restful endpoint in a Springboot Secured application

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I want to expose an unsecure Restful endpoint in a Springboot secured application. GET requests to the endpoint /api/notify work, but POST requests result in a 403. How do I configure so that remote clients can POST to /api/notify from there server?

My extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter looks like this:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/reset").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/notify").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the controller methods that /api/notify map to?

Comment: I would suspect that the csfr protection is holding you back. When posting Spring Security checks if a csfr token is part of the form submit it isn't access is disallowed. When using java-config this is enabled by default disable with `http.csfr().disable();`.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityCtxConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                        "<YOUR URL>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the folllowing configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //This reads, invoke this configuration only when
    //the pattern "/api/notify" is found.
    //When this configuration is invoked, restrict access,
    //disable CSRF, and if the path matches "/api/notify" permit all.
    http.antMatcher("/api/notify")
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/notify")
        .permitAll();

    //Your other configuration...
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/reset").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: GET is accepted, POST is still forbidden, I added my controller method above.

Comment: And my controller is annotated with @RestController

Comment: @darrenrose, I've updated my answer. That said, this answer is meant to give you an idea on how to implement your final solution.